# Iterate through vector up to specific element in vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to iterate through a vector, but I need it to stop at a certain element, because I only want to cout a specific number of elements within the vector

For instance, I have a vector of structs (Relevance) and I need to cout the first 2 elements in the vector (this number will depend on user input)

```
for(std::vector<Relevance>::const_iterator it = RelStructs.begin(); it < RelStructs[2]; ++it)
{

 cout << "\nDesc2: " << it->desc2 << "\n";  // desc2 is a variable within the Relevance struct

 cout << "Relevance2: " << it->relevance2 << "\n\n"; // relevance2 is a variable within the Relevance struct
```

I know this code won't work, but I'm trying to do something like this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, just add the number you want to `begin()`

```
for (std::vector<Relevance>::const_iterator it = RelStructs.begin(); 
    it < RelStructs.begin() + 2; ++it)
{
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if there are less than two elements in `RelStructs`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl thanks for that tidbit. i'll set up constraints. thanks john. i love vectors

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the sequence `v.begin(), v.begin() + std::min<std::size_t>(count, v.size())`:

```
for (std::vector<Relevance>::const_iterator it(RelStructs.begin()),
     end(it + std::min<std::size_t>(RelStructs.size(), count);
     it != end; ++it) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `userEnteredNumber` is the number up to which you need to iterate through the vector, then the following should work:

```
for (int i = 0; userEnteredNumber < RelStructs.size() && i < userEnteredNumber; i++)
{
    std::vector<RelStructs> v = RelStructs[i];
    // do something with v.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class has a suitable `operator <<` defined, you could use [`std::copy_n()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) and [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) instead of rolling your own `for`-loop:

```
size_t number_of_elements = 2;
std::copy_n(std::begin(RelStructs),
    std::min(number_of_elements, RelStructs.size()),
    std::ostream_iterator<Relevance>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

The call to [`std::min()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) ensures you don't run off the end of `RelStructs`, particularly since `number_of_elements` comes from user input.

Your `operator <<` would probably look something like this (and would be usable elsewhere, I am sure):

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Relevance const& rel)
{
    return os << "\nDesc2: " << rel.desc2 << "\n" << "Relevance2: " 
              << rel.relevance2 << "\n\n";
}
```